# Python validar formato fecha dd/mm/yy

Tags: python, date, datetime

Estoy intentado pasar un string a datetime, el string viene de la siguiente manera:

```
day = 02.11.20

date_day = datetime.strptime(day, date_format)

Error: date_str: 02.11.20 Format:['%d.%m.%Y']
```

No se que formato tengo que poner a la fecha, porque si utilizo `[%d.%m.%Y]` me busca el año con cuatro numeros.

¿Hay forma de que detecte que el año viene con dos numeros?

Comment: [%d.%m.%Y] no es una expresión regular. Publica el código con que intentas extraer la fecha.

Comment: Perdona, me lie con otra cosa, ahora si esta mejor explicado mi problema.

Comment: `day = 02.11.20` -> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa "%y" para reconocer al año con dos dígitos:

```
from datetime import datetime

day="02.11.20"
date_format="%d.%m.%y"
date_day = datetime.strptime(day, date_format)
print(date_day)
```

produce

```
2020-11-02 00:00:00
```